# IE 11 response payload size

Tags: api, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I've a webservice which sends payload in JSON format but the value in one of the key of response json is 7.5MB.

Chrome:
It accept the full response.

IE 11:
It terminates the response.

Is there any limit in IE.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I try to find the documentation which shows the limit but I did not get any documentation about that.

I find one article, In which it shows different test results.

[HOW BIG IS TOO BIG FOR JSON?](https://joshzeigler.com/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json)

Test was done with IE 9 and it was able to handle 38 MB of JSON data.

So from that result, We can say that IE 11 can handle at least 38 MB or more data.